# SSIS package skips the last row

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2008, dtexec, uc4

This question was asked here.
[SSIS Package not reading the last row in flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702985/ssis-package-not-reading-the-last-row-in-flat-file)

I believe I have some extra perspective on it.
I have a SSIS package that does simple data flow task which loads Flat file to Sql  Server. The file has a Header, 5000 data row, Footer.

Right off the bat, the package throws the warning "Partial end of the file". Clearly something is different about the file, but I can't tell what.

> Ran through VS STUDIO 2008 -  Loaded 5000 rows [ GOOD]
>
> Ran through SQl server agent [ 32 bit, 64 bit] -  Loaded 5000 rows [Good]
>
> Ran through UC4(DTEXEC command [64bit, 32 bit] - Loaded 4999 rows [ Bad]

My next move was, I took the last row and I placed it somewhere in the middle,
The DTEXEC loaded 5000 rows. Well, that just tells me, there isn't anything wrong with the last row.

Any Ideas

Comment: What encoding in the flat file? Did you copy and paste to an editor as suggested in the thread (like NP++) to check for odd/out of place characters? Are you skipping an additional header row somehow?

Comment: UTF-8 . Yes. I matched the Line Ending char and the encoding of the bad file with the good files. It seems the issue is beyond the encoding and the line ending Char.